# WebDriver: Possible to Create x2 Seperate 'Cookie' Session with the same Browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

WebDriver: Possible to Create x2 Separate 'Cookie' Session with the same Browser?

1. I have altered code within my TestNG file which will execute two test classes at the same time by using x2 seperate threads.
2. The issue: within my test scripts 'A user will log into their account', but when the two scripts are running the test fails because they both use the same account/login details.
3. Is it possible to use the same login account details and same browser when executing more than one+ WebDriver test?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you want two sessions you will need to run separate browsers as two different services.